# Download Data and display it in listview

Tags: android, listview

i have build an application the user can download with one button click an image and attachments text file (in two separate folder one folder for store image and the other for text file )

now I would like build an listview for display this data, each row contain image (ImageView) and name of image (textView) and when user click on it i would like display the attachments  text file

DownloadFile code :

```
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
                String filetxtUrl = strings[0];   
                String filetxtName = strings[1];  
                String fileImageUrl = strings[2];
                String fileImageName = strings[3];


                String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString(); //(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) 
                File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "folder");
                if (!folder.exists()) {
                    folder.mkdirs();
                }


                File folder1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/"
                        + "folder" , "txt");
                if (!folder1.exists()) {
                    folder1.mkdirs();
                }

                File TxtFile = new File(folder1, filetxtName);


                File folder3 = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/"
                        + "folder" , "Image");
                if (!folder3.exists()) {
                    folder3.mkdirs();
                }

                File ImageFile = new File(folder3, fileImageName);

                try{
                    TxtFile.createNewFile();
                    ImageFile.createNewFile();
                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                FileDownloader.downloadFile(filetxtUrl, TxtFile);
                FileDownloader.downloadFile(fileImageUrl, ImageFile);

                L.m("File Download successufuly in Sdcard0 ");    

                return null;
            }
```

FileDownloader code :

```
        private static final int  MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;

        public static void downloadFile(String fileUrl, File directory){
            try {

                URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();


                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(directory);


                byte[] buffer = new byte[MEGABYTE];
                int bufferLength = 0;
                while((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer))>0 ){
                    fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                }
                fileOutputStream.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
             L.m(""+e);   
             } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                 L.m(""+e);   
            } catch (IOException e) {
                 L.m(""+e);   
            }
        }   
}
```

I want use the code below to read the the txt files attachment

```
public void displayOutput()
{
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(sdcard,"/TextFile.txt");
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error reading file!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File not found!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    TextView output=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.output); 
    // Assuming that 'output' is the id of your TextView
    output.setText(text);
}
```

Comment: And...??? What is the question/problem?

Comment: i want Retrieve data stored and display its in listview So when click in image i would like display the attachments text file

Comment: Still no question. Still no problem mentioned.

Comment: sir i have 2 folder directory one for image and the second for txt file In the sense that each image corresponding file txt     Q-How Retrieve data stored in this folder and display its in listview !!!

Comment: So it was irrelevant to post all that download code. Code for displaying images from a folder in a ListView  has been posted on this and other sites many times. A little googling will give you many hits.

Comment: you not understand !!! if I had found something  whith googling so why I posted my question !!

Comment: So you did not google for: android display images from sd card in listview